# Best way to represent this using Python data structures

Tags: python, data-structures

```
  <specification> 
    <propertyName> string </propertyName>
    <value> 
      <number> 
        <value> anyNumberHere </value>
      </number>
      <text> 
        <value> anyTextHere </value>
      </text>
      <URL> 
        <value> anyURIHere </value>
      </URL>
    </value>
    <!-- ... 1 or more value nodes here ... -->
  </specification>
  <!-- ... 1 or more specification nodes here ... -->
```

I need to construct this request for an API, where user will pass these values. So, what should be the best way to represent this, so that it is easy for the user of the method to pass the respective values to the operation?

I am thinking:

*List of List of Dicts:*

```
[specification1, specification2, specification3]
```

Where:

```
specification1= [value1, value2]
```

Where:

```
value1 = {number:anyNumberHere, text:anyTextHere, URL:anyURIHere}
value2 = {number:anyNumberHere, text:anyTextHere, URL:anyURIHere}
```

But, I am not able to accommodate: `<propertyName>` here. Any suggestions?

More over, it sounds way to complicated. Can we have object encapsulation like we do it in Java? I understand, we can, but I am curious, what is the *recommended* way in python?

```
My logic for now, suggestions (incorrect due to propertyName):
    #specification is a List of List of Dicts
    for spec in specification:
        specification_elem = etree.SubElement(root, "specification")
        propertyName_elem = etree.SubElement(specification_elem,"propertyName")
        propertyName_elem.text = spec_propertyName

        for value in spec:
            value_elem = etree.SubElement(specification_elem, "value")
            for key in value:
                key_elem = etree.SubElement(value_elem, key)
                keyValue_elem = etree.SubElement(key_elem, "value")
                keyValue_elem.text = value[key]
```

Here, I will pass `spec_propertyName`, as a diff parameter. So, user will pass: `specification and spec_propertyName`

Comment: Do all three have to be specified?

Comment: That depends, all 3 can be there, or only 1 of number, text and url can be there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a list of Specification objects, of which each has a `property_name` and a list of `value` dictionaries?  (`values` could be a list of objects instead of dictionaries.)

For example:

```
class Value(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 number=None,
                 text=None,
                 url=None):
        self.number = number
        self.text = text
        self.url = url

class Specification(object):
    def __init__(self, propertyName):
        self.propertyName = propertyName
        self.values = []

spec1 = Specification("Spec1")
spec1.values = [Value(number=3,
                      url="http://www.google.com"),
                Value(text="Hello, World!",
                      url="http://www.jasonfruit.com")]

spec2 = Specification("Spec2")
spec2.values = [Value(number=27,
                      text="I can haz cheezburger?",
                      url="http://stackoverflow.com"),
                Value(text="Running out of ideas.",
                      url="http://news.google.com")]
```

Comment: any starters on how to go about it?

Comment: @zengr - I added a starter for you.

Comment: +1 Python is not like some languages where you seem to need to define a new class for *everything*. But that doesn't mean you should use lists, dicts and tuples for everything, either. In this example, the classes add a lot of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If propertyNames are unique, you can have a dict of list of dict. If they are not, you can have a list of list of list of dict.

If all those lists end up hard to keep track of, you can make a class to store the data:

```
class Specification:
    def __init__(self):
        self.propertyName = ""
        self.values = []
```

Then, use:

```
spec = Specification()
spec.propertyName = "string"
value = {"URL":"someURI", "text":"someText"}
spec.values.append(value)
```

Comment: propertyNames is unique for specification. There can be multiple specification.

Comment: oh I see... yeah I think the object approach would be best here, to reduce confusion.

Comment: I am a python noob here, been 2 days I am using python, any starters?

Comment: See edit for something that should work. I don't code in python that often so I always have http://docs.python.org/ open to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a representation approach using [named tuples](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields). You can upgrade to using classes (adding code to do some validation on the caller's input, and allowing the omission of `field=None` for optional fields) at your leisure with no other change to the user API and little change to the ElementTree-building code.

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

from collections import namedtuple
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

Specifications = namedtuple('Specifications', 'specification_list')
Specification = namedtuple('Specification', 'propertyName value_list')
Value = namedtuple('Value', 'number text url')

def make_etree(specifications, encoding):
    """ 
    Convert user's `specifications` to an ElementTree.
    `encoding` is encoding of *input* `str` objects.
    """
    def ensure_unicode(v):
        if isinstance(v, str): return v.decode(encoding)
        if isinstance(v, unicode): return v
        return unicode(v) # convert numbers etc to unicode strings  

    root = etree.Element('specifications')
    for spec in specifications.specification_list:
        specification_elem = etree.SubElement(root, "specification")
        propertyName_elem = etree.SubElement(specification_elem, "propertyName")
        propertyName_elem.text = ensure_unicode(spec.propertyName)
        for value in spec.value_list:
            value_elem = etree.SubElement(specification_elem, "value")
            for key in value._fields:
                kv = getattr(value, key)
                if kv is None: continue
                key_elem = etree.SubElement(value_elem, key)
                keyValue_elem = etree.SubElement(key_elem, "value")
                keyValue_elem.text = ensure_unicode(kv)
    return etree.ElementTree(root)

# === sample caller code follows ===

specs = Specifications(
    specification_list=[
        Specification(
            propertyName='a prop',
            value_list=[
                Value(
                    number=42,
                    text='universe', 
                    url='http://uww.everywhere',
                    ),
                Value(
                    number=0,
                    text=None, # optional
                    url='file:///dev/null',
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        Specification(
            propertyName='b prop',
            value_list=[
                Value(
                    number=1,
                    text='Üñîçøðè', # str object, encoded in cp1252
                    url=u'Üñîçøðè', # unicode object
                    ),
                ],           
            ),
        ],
    )

print repr(specs); print

import sys
tree = make_etree(specs, 'cp1252')
import cStringIO
f = cStringIO.StringIO()
tree.write(f, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
print repr(f.getvalue())
print
```

Output (folded at column 80):

```
Specifications(specification_list=[Specification(propertyName='a prop', value_li
st=[Value(number=42, text='universe', url='http://uww.everywhere'), Value(number
=0, text=None, url='file:///dev/null')]), Specification(propertyName='b prop', v
alue_list=[Value(number=1, text='\xdc\xf1\xee\xe7\xf8\xf0\xe8', url=u'\xdc\xf1\x
ee\xe7\xf8\xf0\xe8')])])

"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<specifications><specification><propert
yName>a prop</propertyName><value><number><value>42</value></number><text><value
>universe</value></text><url><value>http://uww.everywhere</value></url></value><
value><number><value>0</value></number><url><value>file:///dev/null</value></url
></value></specification><specification><propertyName>b prop</propertyName><valu
e><number><value>1</value></number><text><value>\xc3\x9c\xc3\xb1\xc3\xae\xc3\xa7
\xc3\xb8\xc3\xb0\xc3\xa8</value></text><url><value>\xc3\x9c\xc3\xb1\xc3\xae\xc3\
xa7\xc3\xb8\xc3\xb0\xc3\xa8</value></url></value></specification></specification
s>"
```

Comment: That's an interesting option --- I hadn't noticed named tuples before.